# How to click iframe element in wordpress (all pages)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, wordpress, iframe

I have a wordpress website, where I have pages with artists. This is an example: http://chasefetti.paradigmrecordsinc.com/ of a page from my website

On the top I have an iframe from arena.com
I want after the page loads to click the play button.
If I do it on the arenas page http://arena.com/artist/chasefetti like this (using firebug):

```
document.getElementsByClassName("fg icon-play-fg")[0].click()
```

it works, but on my website I guess it doesn't know about accessing the iframe.

How can I specify to access that iframe ?

Also the full mission that I gotta do is to play that button for each page. I am thinking to add a jquery that does what I want to do, to the templates page.

My main problem is accessing that element from the iframe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know(I tired it once) you can't do that, unless the source of the iframe is on the same site as yours, which isn't the case here.

Also check this [same-origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy).

Comment: isn't there ANYWAY to do this ?

Comment: No, at least none I know of. There was another question here, where it was explained in more detail but I can't find it. What I can tell you is that it has to do with security, but what exactly, I don't remember. If I find the question I will link it.

Comment: it looks like you're right, nobody answered something that can be done